# Can I declare a struct field with two data types?

Tags: go, generics, union-types

```
type Human struct {
   Name string
   Age string | int  // <--- this is the problem
}
```

I want to do something like Node.js and declare a field with a union  type.

Comment: This is called union types and golang doesn't have it. If you _want_ this flexibility, you'll have to use `any`.

Comment: The most appropriate solution will depend on the context (mainly, how the data type will be used).

Comment: If by `interface{}` you mean the *empty interface* and not interface types in general, then you can declare unions with [General interfaces](https://go.dev/ref/spec#General_interfaces): *"In their most general form, an interface element may also be an arbitrary type term `T`, or a term of the form `~T` specifying the underlying type `T`, **or a union of terms `t1|t2|…|tn`**."*